# how to fix issue related to file path in flask app

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, path

i have written the follwoing code for my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Retrieve the initial JSON files
        json_files_initial = request.files.getlist('json_file_desc2')
        save_directory_initial = 'D:/../../../descriptors_2'  # Specify the directory to save the initial JSON files
        for json_file_initial in json_files_initial:
            if json_file_initial:
                json_filename_initial = json_file_initial.filename
                json_file_initial.save(os.path.join(save_directory_initial, json_filename_initial))

        generate_info_txt = request.form.get('generate_info_txt')

        if generate_info_txt == 'yes':
            # Retrieve the latter task JSON files
            json_files_latter = request.files.getlist('json_file_desc3')
            save_directory_latter = 'D:/../../../descriptors_3'  # Specify the directory to save the latter task JSON files
            for json_file_latter in json_files_latter:
                if json_file_latter:
                    json_filename_latter = json_file_latter.filename
                    json_file_latter.save(os.path.join(save_directory_latter, json_filename_latter))

        # Run the 'nocodegen-test.py' script
        #os.system('python path/to/nocodegen-test.py')

        return "Files saved and script executed successfully!"

    return render_template('index.html', template_folder='flasktemp')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**and the path to this app.py is:
D:/../../src/app.py

and also the path to the index.html is:
D:/../../src/flasktemp/index.html

and upon executing the app.py
i am getting the following error:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html**

someone please help with this issue, as i am not able to understand what the issue is here.

Comment: "`d:/`" starts an absolute path, but you want to use relative pathing within it. Are you sure that is what you want to do?

Comment: how can i use relative pathing in this case? and may I ask what difference does it make?